# How do you manage your Linux iptables configuration on a machine acting as a router?

Tags: linux, router, iptables, gateway

I have a couple Linux machines that act as routers/firewalls for my networks and I have a script that runs all the iptables commands to set my rules. This seems to me like a really silly way to do it though.

How do you do this? Is there a program with config files that are a bit easier to manage? Does it have a GUI or web interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use [firehol](http://firehol.sourceforge.net/) combined with a web interface that I developed to manage the configuration file.

I really like firehol, it provides a simplier syntax then using iptables directly.

- You can use the firehol debug command to exactly what iptables commands are generated
- If you have an error in your configuration and you start the firewall, firehol detects the error and reverts to the previous state.
- Firehol has a 'try' command which you can use to start the firewall remotely, if your changes kill your connection, firehol will revert to the previous state, if you didn't kill your connection then it will ask you to confirm the change.
- Firehol has a large set of services pre-defined so you don't have to remember exactly what ports you have to have what ports to open for some obscure protocol.

Answer (score 4):

For RedHat and related OSs (and perhaps for others), you can use the script to create the firewall, and then `service iptables ...` to handle it from there.  This is what I do.  When I change my iptables configuration, I use a script.  Then I save it with

```
service iptables save
```

At this point, the machine will now always come up with the new rules.  You can dump a brief version of your current rules with

```
service iptables status
```

Answer (score 4):

We've used [shorewall](https://shorewall.org/) - "iptables made easy".
A GUI is available via [Webmin](http://webmin.net/) 1.060 and later

> The Shoreline Firewall, more commonly known as “Shorewall”, is high-level tool for configuring Netfilter. You describe your firewall/gateway requirements using entries in a set of configuration files. Shorewall reads those configuration files and with the help of the iptables, iptables-restore, ip and tc utilities, Shorewall configures Netfilter and the Linux networking subsystem to match your requirements. Shorewall can be used on a dedicated firewall system, a multi-function gateway/router/server or on a standalone GNU/Linux system.

Answer (score 3):

I can't see anything wrong with your method, assuming each machine has different rules.

The way I normally setup firewall rules is by entering them normally on the command line and then running `iptables-save > /etc/iptables_rules`, I'll then insert the following into `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/iptables` so when the network interface starts the rules are automatically imported.

```
#!/bin/bash
/sbin/iptables-restore < /etc/iptables_rules
```

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Firewall Builder](http://www.fwbuilder.org) and I quite like it - it's a GUI program that's designed for managing firewall configurations, primarily on remote hosts which could be servers, routers, whatever. The interface looks a little intimidating at first but in my experience, it's worth the couple of hours or so it takes to figure it out. (And apparently they just recently released version 3 since I last checked, so quite possibly the GUI has gotten more intuitive)

Comment: That's now abandonware - the website no longer works and the last date on the copyright line at the bottom of http://fwbuilder.sourceforge.net/ is 2012.

Answer (score 2):

I do exactly what you have described, except **separating the rules into several sub-files** (private, dmz, vpn), and setting up a file of **variables** to make the rules more readable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [pfSense](http://pfsense.org) instead for your router, it has many [features](http://www.pfsense.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=40&Itemid=43):

- Firewall
- Network Address Translation (NAT)
- Redundancy
- Load Balancing
  Reporting and Monitoring
- RRD Graphs

  The RRD graphs in pfSense maintain historical information on the following.

  - CPU utilization
  - Total throughput
  - Firewall states
  - Individual throughput for all interfaces
  - Packets per second rates for all interfaces
  - WAN interface gateway(s) ping response times
  - Traffic shaper queues on systems with traffic shaping enable
- VPN

  - IPsec
  - PPTP
  - OpenVPN
- Dynamic DNS

  Through:

  - DynDNS
  - DHS
  - DyNS
  - easyDNS
  - No-IP
  - ODS.org
  - ZoneEdit
- Captive Portal
- DHCP Server and Relay

#### It has a nice, easy to use web-based configuration, just look at the [screen-shots](http://www.pfsense.org/screenshots/).

Best of all you can build it yourself with commodity hardware, and it's [Open Source](http://www.google.com/search?btnI=&q=site%3Apfsense.org%20license%20pfsense).